# A control that looks like searching people in SMS composing window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, addressbook

I am looking for a control, class or nib file looks like "SMS or Email writing window".
In order to do my job, it should have these particular functions.

1. Has to look for the people in Addressbook.
2. When person is selected, it should return person's name and placed in the UITextField.
3. Has to be searched by person's surname or firstname.

If you see this screen capture, you will understand more easily.
But I am a new user in this web site, and I cannot upload the picture that I wanna show you guys.

Can anyone give me some clue how to solve this out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're never going to get something that perfectly fits your very specific needs like that.  To get the user info you'll want to look into **[Address Book Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744).** To get the SMS view, here are two classes to get you started:

---

**[SSMessagesViewController](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller)**

[image]

---

**[AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to interact with the [Address Book UI Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1).